# 100% Ajax Websites

Tags: ajax, client-side

I have been looking at Hulu's new website and I am very impressed from a developer's standpoint (as well as a designer's).

I have found that, unless you switch between http/https, you are served content entirely from json requests. That is a HUGE feat to have this level of ajax while maintaining browse back button support as well as allowing each url to be visited directly.

I want to create a website like this as a learning experience. Is there any type of framework out there that can give me this kind of support?

I was thinking I could...

- leverage jQuery
- use clientside MVVM frameworks like KnockoutJS?
- use ASP.NET MVC content negotiation to serve html or json determined by an accept header.
- using the same codebase.
- use the same template for client side and server side rendering
- provide ways to update pagetitle/meta tags/etc.

Ajax forms/widgets/etc would still be used, by I am thinking about page level ajax using json and client side templates.

What do you think? Any frameworks out there? Any patterns I could follow?

Comment: Why not write it yourself? Just catch/handle all page transitions and pass the page transition to the server (from page, to page, etc) and have the server figure out what it needs to send back, and then just swap the content of certain sections (divs) of the page.

Comment: Look into frameworks like backbone.js.

Comment: I personally don't like backbone.js because it forces users to enable javascript. I like graceful degradation.

Comment: KnockoutJS is the de-facto standard for ASP.NET. Probably because the creator, Steve Sanderson, is currently employed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always best to first build a website without AJAX support, then add AJAX on top of that. Doing this means that:

- users without javascript can already access your website
- users can already visit any URL directly.

Adding AJAX support can be accomplished by various javascript libraries. So that you can render json content, you will want to look at **javascript templating**. You will want to use javascript templating even on your server side for when you add AJAX support (file extension .ejs). This will probably require some appropriate libraries to run javascript on the server.

When you add AJAX support, you will want to use the "History.js" library for browser back/forward/history support.

Make no mistake. This is a HUGE project (unless your website only has a few pages). So it is going to take a LONG time to add all the AJAX support to the best possible standard.

Comment: I agree with a progressive enhancement approach, but some websites can afford to drop js/ie6 support like entertainment websites. Visit hulu.com without js enabled and you will see what I mean. Also, since each page can be visited directly, I think progressive enhancement is still do-able.

Comment: But yes, this would be a LARGE endeavor for, lets say, an eCommerce site. I was hoping someone went through the trials and tribulations and could share their experiences, or better yet, a framework to use that combines multiple technologies together on both the client and the server.

Comment: You definitely want to template your views with javascript (probably ejs which stands for embedded javascript), so that you can render your views on both server side and client side using the same code. That way you don't have to do this twice.

Comment: Is there an MVC view engine for ejs? So I am understanding this correctly, I can render the template server side, and then render that same template client side using the same exact model represented as json (rather than a .net object)?

Comment: Well, I have only really investigated this possibility for Ruby on Rails (there are ejs renderers for Ruby). For server-side, there are libraries for different frameworks that parse ejs. Just searching quickly, I couldn't find a library for asp.net, but there may be. Many client-side javascript frameworks support ejs (using json variables).

Answer (score 0):

to answer your bullet point about using the same template server side as well as client side: check out[dust](http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/).  It was originally developed by [akdubya](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/), but has since been adopted and enhanced by linkedin.  They use it to render templates on their mobile app [client side](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates).  Personally I've used it on the server side and it works great.